# cassandra nodetool : Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, connectexception

i installed cassandra 3.11.3-1 on centos7 & vmware

i didn't have error while installing cassandra. 
i started cassandra and faced this logs.

```
[root@localhost ~]# service cassandra start
Starting cassandra (via systemctl):                        [  OK  ]

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status cassandra
cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: deactivating (stop) (Result: exit-code) since 2018-08-02 15:15:45 
KST; 6s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 10366 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 10450 (code=exited, status=3);         : 10478 (cassandra)
Tasks: 2
CGroup: /system.slice/cassandra.service
         └─control
            ├─10478 /bin/bash /etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra stop
            └─10549 sleep 0.5

 02 15:15:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed 
 stora....
 02 15:15:39 localhost.localdomain su[10376]: (to cassandra) root on none
 02 15:15:41 localhost.localdomain cassandra[10366]: Starting Cassandra: OK
 02 15:15:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started LSB: distributed 
 storag....
  02 15:15:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: cassandra.service: main 
 process...D
 02 15:15:45 localhost.localdomain su[10489]: (to cassandra) root on none
 02 15:15:45 localhost.localdomain cassandra[10478]: Shutdown Cassandra: 
 bash: …
 Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

it means 'cassandra starting is ok' right? 
but when i check the node status like this 
    "nodetool status"

then i met this logs.

```
    "] nodetool status" 
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 
Connection refused)
```

so i searched a lot on google. 
i found some information. 
so i tried this.

1. edit cassandra-env.sh 
   "JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
2. expend memory size : 1GB -> 2GB

but i still faced same error.

someone help me please.

------------- system.log ----------------------------------

INFO  [main] 2018-08-02 15:15:44,866 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml

ERROR [main] 2018-08-02 15:15:45,043 CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
Error: while scanning a simple key; could not found expected ':';  in 'reader', line 601, column 1:

## Set listen_address OR listen_i ...

Comment: what your system logs say ?

Comment: Adding to Payals comment. The system.log is usually available in /usr/share/cassandra/logs or /var/log/cassandra.

Comment: @Payal i added system.log above

Comment: It says something is wrong in your cassandra.yaml file, can you paste your cassandra.yaml file and full error message from system.log file.

Comment: Active: deactivating **(stop)** (Result: exit-code) since 2018-08-02 15:15:45 seems it's not running.

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to make sure that the activated version of OpenJDK should be `openjdk-8-jdk`. If you have multiple versions of OpenJDK on your machine, then you could follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04) to set a default version (in this case `openjdk-8-jdk`).

Then, you need to check the status of cassandra service again. The result for activating cassandra service should be as following

[image]

After that, you can follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41807621/5657159) to modify `JVM_OPTS` in `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`. In my case, I do not need to follow 2nd step. Finally, when checking status of a node, you should see the result as following

[image]

Comment: The above answer didn't completely get it working for me. I had to update permissions for Cassandra. I followed this answer here(https://askubuntu.com/questions/999834/can-not-open-var-log-cassandra-gc-log-due-to-permission-denied) and it go it working. Look for the comment by me(Daniel Blythe) for more info or enter commands `sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /var/lib/cassandra/` and `sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /var/log/cassandra/` then `$ cassandra` on its own presumably to start Cassandra. Then `nodetools status` and it should work/connect

Answer (score 1):

The cassandra service takes some time to start. After the install, check whether the service has started by using

```
service  --status-all
```

and you will see something like this

```
 [ + ]  cassandra
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ - ]  ntp
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  udev
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

if you see a - sign instead of a + sign next to cassandra, it would mean that service has not yet started. you can start it by issuing this command

```
service cassandra restart
```

keep checking the status until you get the a +. Now you should be able to execute the nodetool command

```
nodetool status
```

and now you should get the desired result, someething like this

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  127.0.0.1  84.76 KiB  16      100.0%            7615cf7e-14cc-4475-bf46-ceeb122b6a12  rack1
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

When I checked this "***systemctl status cassandra***" I could see ***Active: failed*** as seen below

> ● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured
> data    Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor
> preset: disabled)    ***Active: failed*** (Result: signal) since Fri
> 2022-01-07 02:28:07 UTC; 10min ago
> Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)  Main PID: 8239 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

So I changed below parameter in ***cassandra-env.sh***

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=***localhost***"

After I changed the parameter I could see this

> [root@ip-172-31-28-163 default.conf]# systemctl status cassandra ●
> cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured
> data    Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor
> preset: disabled)    ***Active: active (running)*** since Fri
> 2022-01-07 02:47:27 UTC; 12min ago
> Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Be sure to do this as root user. Be careful as well

Answer (score 0):

Check in the file  cassandra-env.sh (/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh) if the parameters  system_memory_in_mb and system_cpu_cores values is configured acoording your machine capabilites

Answer (score -1):

Another solution. In my case I was installing Cassandra 41x with older Java  8 Version which caused an issue and in case to solve this I installed new Java 11. Just provision right version of Java.