# How to enable full query logging on a Cassandra 4.0 Docker container?

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-4.0

I'd like to run a Docker container running Cassandra 4 with [Full Query Logging (FQL)](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/fqllogging.html) enabled. So far I've tried to build the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM cassandra:4.0
RUN nodetool enablefullquerylog
```

but this fails with the following error:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

I've also tried to to uncomment the `full_query_logging_options` in the `cassandra.yaml` located in `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` on the Docker container:

```yaml
# default options for full query logging - these can be overridden from command line when executing
# nodetool enablefullquerylog
full_query_logging_options:
    log_dir: /var/log/cassandra/fql.log
    roll_cycle: HOURLY
    block: true
    max_queue_weight: 268435456 # 256 MiB
    max_log_size: 17179869184 # 16 GiB
    # archive command is "/path/to/script.sh %path" where %path is replaced with the file being rolled:
    archive_command:
    max_archive_retries: 10
```

Ideally, I would like to enable FQL in the `cassandra.yaml` without having to use a `nodetool` command, but it seems that this is not possible (it is only possible to configure its options given that it has been enabled using `nodetool`)?

I'm also unsure how to change the `cassandra.yaml` in order to allow `nodetool` to connect. I've noticed that in the `cassandra` Docker image which runs Cassandra 3, the `nodetool` command works; it just doesn't work in the `cassandra:4.0` image. From [Cassandra failed to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776345/cassandra-failed-to-connect), it seems that what is needed is to configure the `listen_address` and `broadcast_address` in the `cassandra.yaml`. In the Cassandra 3 Docker container, I can see this is configured by default as follows:

```yaml
# Address or interface to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to.
# You _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to communicate!
#
# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both.
#
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
#
# Setting listen_address to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
#
listen_address: 172.17.0.5

# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both. Interfaces must correspond
# to a single address, IP aliasing is not supported.
# listen_interface: eth0

# If you choose to specify the interface by name and the interface has an ipv4 and an ipv6 address
# you can specify which should be chosen using listen_interface_prefer_ipv6. If false the first ipv4
# address will be used. If true the first ipv6 address will be used. Defaults to false preferring
# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
# listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false

# Address to broadcast to other Cassandra nodes
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
broadcast_address: 172.17.0.5
```

whereas in the Cassandra 4 container it is

```yaml
# Address or interface to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to.
# You _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to communicate!
#
# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both.
#
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be). If unresolvable
# it will fall back to InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), which is wrong for production systems.
#
# Setting listen_address to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
#
listen_address: localhost

# Set listen_address OR listen_interface, not both. Interfaces must correspond
# to a single address, IP aliasing is not supported.
# listen_interface: eth0

# If you choose to specify the interface by name and the interface has an ipv4 and an ipv6 address
# you can specify which should be chosen using listen_interface_prefer_ipv6. If false the first ipv4
# address will be used. If true the first ipv6 address will be used. Defaults to false preferring
# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
# listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false

# Address to broadcast to other Cassandra nodes
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
# broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
```

I don't quite understand where the `172.17.0.5` 'comes from' and why setting it to that value in the `cassandra.yaml` would allow `nodetool` to work on the container. Any ideas how to use `nodetool` on the Cassandra 4 container to enable FQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by default, you cannot run `nodetool` commands in the `Dockerfile` when building the container; rather, they have to be run  'manually' in the running container. So I adapted the `Dockerfile` to the following:

```
FROM cassandra:4.0
RUN mkdir /cassandra-fql && chmod 777 /cassandra-fql
COPY cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

with the `cassandra.yaml` the same as the default one except for the following `full_query_logging_options`:

```yaml
# default options for full query logging - these can be overridden from command line when executing
# nodetool enablefullquerylog
full_query_logging_options:
    log_dir: /cassandra-fql
    roll_cycle: HOURLY
    block: true
    max_queue_weight: 268435456 # 256 MiB
    max_log_size: 17179869184 # 16 GiB
    # archive command is "/path/to/script.sh %path" where %path is replaced with the file being rolled:
    # archive_command:
    max_archive_retries: 10
```

Then, after running the container like so,

```
docker run --name cassandra-fql -p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042 cassandra-fql
```

and `docker exec`ing into it, running `nodetool enablefullquerylog` was successful.